# Grid with three rows, one is collapsable (DataGrid, GridSplitter, TextBox). Grid is not resizing as I would like

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel, wpf-grid

I have a problem with my `Grid` layout. I would like to have three rows (second with `GridSplitter`) with behavior:

If the row with `TextBox` is `Collapsed`, then `DataGrid` fill whole space.
If the row with `TextBox` is `Visible`, then `TextBox` and `DataGrid` share space.
If the `Text` is set in `TextBox`, `TextBox` is not expanding `Height`. 
`TextBox` and `DataGrid` fills theirs rows.

Example xaml:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox x:Name="ShowTextBox" Content="Show TextBox"/>
        <Button Content="Add text" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Aqua">
            <DataGrid/>
        </StackPanel>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                      Height="5"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ResizeDirection="Rows"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=ShowTextBox, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="2"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=ShowTextBox, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" x:Name="TextBox"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Problem 1:
When I change `Height` of `TextBox` row and set it `Collapsed`, then `DataGrid` will not fill empty space.
[image: (1) start (2) problem]

I would like to have `DataGrid` expanded to whole area.

Problem 2:
If I don't touch `TextBox` row `Height` and add multiple lines of text then `TextBox` will expand `Height`. If `Height` of `TextBox` row was previously changed, then no problem appear.
[image: (1) start (2) problem (3) target]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The behaviors you've listed sound more like a dockpanel.  Could you use a border inside of a dockpanel?

Comment: How can I achieve behavior of GridSplitter with DockPanel? 
This setting allows me to manually control share ratio of DataGrid and TextBox. Without GridSplitter feature it will behave like simple DockPanel. I saw that there is some online solution for 'DockPanelSplitter' but I would like to use build-in WPF mechanism.